# Check if a JSON key has data in it or not in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Apps script fetching data from WooCommerce store in Google Sheet with all the order details. One of the details that I want is the coupon code used. The problem is that not all orders have it and if I just include the JSON key containing the coupon code then code breaks for orders that doesn't have it.

Basically in the JSON response that WooCommerce API sends back has `"coupon_lines": []` and it is blank for most of the orders and for orders having coupon code, this key looks like:

[image]

I have tried doing code like this

```
if (params[i]["coupon_lines"][0]["code"]){
        a = container.push(params[i]["coupon_lines"][0]["code"]);
        }
```

Or,

```
if (params[i]["coupon_lines"][0]["code"]!= null){
        a = container.push(params[i]["coupon_lines"][0]["code"]);
        }
```

But it doesn't work. Or If I just add `a = container.push(params[i]["coupon_lines"][0]["code"])`  without if condition then it breaks and all 3 scenarios result in `Cannot read property 'code' of undefined`

I wonder if there is something like PHP's `isset` in Apps script to test if a variable or key has some value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the if "coupon_lines" has any elements before getting an element property

```
if (params[i]["coupon_lines"][0] && params[i]["coupon_lines"][0]["code"]){
    //
}
```